# Update LastModifiedDate of owned entity

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-repositories

I have two objects. Workflow and Task. Task does contain workflow.

```
@Entity
public class Workflow {

  @Column(name = "last_modified_date")
  private Date lastModifiedDate;
...}


@Entity
@EntityListeners(TaskAuditListener.class)
public class Task {

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "workflow_id")
  private Workflow workflow;
...}
```

On any update of Task object, I want to update lastModifiedDate value on Workflow. To avoid repetitive code, I would like to use TaskAuditListener with @PreUpdate.

```
@Component
public class TaskAuditListener {

  private static WorkflowRepository workflowRepository;

  @Autowired
  public void TaskAuditListener(WorkflowRepository workflowRepository) {
    TaskAuditListener.workflowRepository = workflowRepository;
  }

  @PreUpdate
  void beforeUpdate(Task task) {
    workflowRepository.updateCreatedByTaskId(task.getId(),
        new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
  }
```

My repository method is this:

```
  @Modifying
  @Transactional
  @Query("UPDATE Workflow w SET w.lastModifiedDate = :lastModifiedDate WHERE w.id = :workflowId")
  void updateLastModifiedDateById(String workflowId, Date lastModifiedDate);
```

The error I am receiving is *java.lang.StackOverflowError: null* and is triggered by the *workflowRepository.updateLastModifiedDateById()* method.

**Why is @PreUpdate cyclically triggered, when in my @Query I update Workflow object, not Task?**

Or is there any better to achieve this?

Comment: Can you tries to code a bit simpler, remove the @EntityListener annotation and TaskAuditListener class. When saving the Task object using the TaskRepository get the return Task object and update the lastModifiedDate using workflowRepository.updateLastModifiedDateById() give it a shot.

Comment: Of course I can do it this way. That would work without any problem. But that does not seem to be a good approach. Each programmer will need not only add new functionality, but also not to forget to update parents lastModifiedDate.

Answer (score 1):

JPA already have annotation for it:

```
@Column(name = "last_modified_date")
@LastModifiedDate
private Date lastModifiedDate;
```

Or you can create method to run before updating:

```
@PreUpdate
protected void onUpdate() {
    lastModifiedDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
}
```

Comment: The problem with both solutions is, that it updates lastModifiedDate only when Workflow is updated. I want to update Task object, which should update value in parent Workflow.

Answer (score 0):

What about: `@UpdateTimestamp` on field `lastModifiedDate`

Comment: You did not fully understand my issue. I do want to update Object1, while updating lastModifiedDate value of Object2. So @UpdateTimestamp does not work here.